# Link user input with login button

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I would like to create a sort of login page. Which links to a href depending on the input of the user.

So i have a text input part and a login button. 
Then it should go to the website depending on the text input.

Example: users fills in 1234 and clicks on the login button, then the website:
example.com/1234 opens up.

I tried but i cant get it worked.

```
<input type=text id='token' name="token"/>
<input type=button name=login value="login" onClick=changeQuery()/>

changeQuery(){
    var input_query=document.getElementById('sq').value;
    window.location="http://www.google.com/"+input_query+"myString";
}
```

Comment: If that is a copy/paste of your HTML, then the issue is you're not putting the attributes in quotes.  Instead of `onclick=changeQuery()` it should be `onclick="changeQuery()"`.  You also appear to be missing the keyword `function` before the actual function

Comment: getElementById('sq') You don't have 'sq' pay attention what you copying and pasting :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues with your code...

- HTML attribute should be in quotes (so change things like `onclick=changeQuery()` to `onclick="changeQuery()"`)
- Your function does not start with the keyword `function`
- Your textbox control has an id of `token`... so in the example you have, there is no `sq` for the `getElementById` to find

And I'm not sure why you're adding "MyString" at the end of the URL, but that might be part of your intended code

The result should be something like this...

```js
function changeQuery(){
    var input_query = document.getElementById('token').value;
    //window.location = "http://www.google.com/" + input_query + "myString";
    console.log("http://www.google.com/" + input_query + "myString");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="token" name="token"/>
<input type="button" name="login" value="login" onClick="changeQuery()"/>
```

(Please note, I've commented out the `window.location` and instead put a `console.log` so you can see what is produced without it actually navigating to another page)

Comment: Thanks! that works. Is it possible to intergrate this into wordpress?

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about wordpress, I was purely working on the problems in your example code.  If you need to ask something specific to integration with wordpress I recommend you ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

```
             function changeQuery() {
               var input_query = 
               document.getElementById('token').value;
               window.location = "https://www.google.com/search? 
               q=" + input_query;
             }
```

Above is the correct code for what you want, but google doesn't allow some different origin to make search request.

Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/search?q=somequery' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.If you try to redirect some other origin it will work.

Comment: thanks, the google.com part was used as an example. next time i will use example.com. sorry about the confusion.

Comment: If that is the case then above code that I shared will work definitely. You can try with https://wikipedia.org to check. :)